# Facebook – Does a page exist for this URL?

Tags: facebook

I'm making a webpage/SEO checking page, where I can put in a URL and it will tell me various facts about the page.

I'd like to be able to tell if there is a Facebook page associated with the URL. Is this possible using the API, or by other means?

For instance, https://www.facebook.com/focalstrategy links to http://www.focalstrategy.com/ on the info tab – is there a way to go the other way and enter the URL and find the page(s)?

(Bonus points – anyone know of a way to do the same for Twitter accounts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **don't** think this is possible. Using the API, you can retrieve info about the url:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.focalstrategy.com/
```

Would return:

```
{
   "id": "http://www.focalstrategy.com/",
   "shares": 38
}
```

Now I'm note sure if using the Open Graph Meta Tags would help return more data (still not what you need), but here is my website info *without* trailing slash:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.masteringapi.com
```

Would return:

```
{
   "id": "109784969102047",
   "name": "MasteringAPI.com",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276619_109784969102047_474156823_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.masteringapi.com/",
   "likes": 25,
   "category": "Website",
   "website": "http://www.masteringapi.com",
   "description": "Master Facebook, Google and Twitter APIs! Learn Facebook Application Development Now!",
   "can_post": true
}
```